# SoapClient и exceptions

Tags: php, soap

Есть класс, унаследованный от `SoapClient`, в конструкторе которого примерно такой код:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $params = array(
        'exceptions'         => true,
        'trace'              => $this->clientOptions['trace'],
        'connection_timeout' => $this->clientOptions['connection_timeout'],
    );
    try {
        parent::__construct($this->getServiceURL(), $params);
        //other actions
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        //Handler
    }
}
```

Строка с обращением к родительскому конструктору валится с `Fatal Error`, в случае, если задать неправильный адрес. При этом параметр `exceptions` включен.

В чем может быть загвоздка?